# Why submodule update --init and SSH results in Permission Denied?

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules

I have two repositories.

*Repo 1* includes *Repo 2* as **Git Submodule**.

When I clone *Repo 1* submodule folder is empty. I've already made some research and found out that first I need to init and update my submodule(every time I clone *Repo 1*): `git submodule update --init`. But when I run this command I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The following is true for these repos:

1. My public ssh key is added to both repos.
2. **I'm able to clone these repos separately.**
3. I don't have access to the web interface of these repos. I only have ssh links.

Also I've played with this and figured out that if I clone *Repo 1* then run `start-ssh-agent` and then add my keys(`ssh-add`) I'm able to update submodule.

Could someone explain why I'm able to clone them separately and have no rights to run `git submodule update --init`? And how can I resolve this problem?